# Getting ï»¿ character in JMeter Response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am calling a login API from JMeter which return result in json format. For this API call I am getting expected result however the json response contains ï»¿ character. In the request I have added, DataType:json and Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8.

Any advice.

[Output Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guHFc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), your server responds this way so you might want to raise an issue against your application if this is not expected.

If your application functions as designed you can remove the BOM from the response using i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, the relevant code would be something like:

```
def BOM = '\uFEFF'
def responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
if (responseData.startsWith(BOM)) {
    responseData = responseData.substring(1)
}
prev.setResponseData(responseData.getBytes('UTF-8'))
```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter